How to fix fallen ceramic tile from top of window
Due to a leak, a horizontal tile from the top of our bathroom window fell. Here's a shot of the window from the inside with the missing tile at top center for context.

The leak seems to be fixed so I'm reattaching the tile. Would anyone be able to answer the following questions for me?

I'd like to match the adhesive. Is this thin set, mastic or something else?
Looking at the adjacent tiles that are still attached, the gap between sill and window is 1/2". Can the adhesive safely fill a gap that large?

The fallen tile has most of the adhesive on it. Any ideas on how to remove it aside from gently going at it with a screwdriver and hammer?


Any tips on the above would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for you input.

This gap is huge for an acrylic tile cement. You should be able to scrape it off down to the setting ridges. Because of the depth, use a mortar like Mega-Lite to reset.

It looks as if the tile was placed with drywall compound.  That was wrong.
Modified thinset should be used to reinstall the tile. Get thinset made for large format tiles. It is formulated to be applied thick.
An option is to attach a 1/4 inch thick piece of cement board with approved screws. Then you don't need the thinset to be so thick.
Mastic is only good for a thin application 1/8 inch or so.

Yup, or leave the old thinset (unless it really is drywall mud...?) on the tile (for thickness) and use construction adhesive to glue it back on.
